# Where are the available debug tokens for the Net-SNMP tools listed?

Tags: snmp, debug, net-snmp

In `snmpcmd(1)`, under "Generic Options", it says,

```
    -D[TOKEN[,...]]
           Turn  on  debugging  output  for  the  given TOKEN(s).  Try ALL for
           extremely verbose output.
```

What tokens could I use besides `ALL`? What do the tokens mean? The tools are very liberal about what tokens they will accept.

```
$ snmpgetnext -Dserverfault_is_awesome [...]
registered debug token serverfault_is_awesome, 1
[...]
```

The best thing I have found so far is a [wiki page talking about v5.4.2.1](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Debug_tokens_5.4.2.1), but it does not address the general problem of listing debug tokens that are valid for the currently installed version (5.7.2 in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself does not maintain a list of available tokens, and MIB developers are free to define their own. So yes, the library will accept any string as a token.

Since there is no internal list, there is no way to report available tokens at run time. All you can do is download the source and run the command suggested on the wiki (which I've just tweaked a little):

```
find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep "DEBUGMSG[A-Z_]*(( *\"" | sed 's/^.*DEBUGMSG[A-Z_]*(( *\"\([^\"]*\).*/\1/' | sort -u
```

I've also added a new wiki page which lists some of the more useful tokens, and a new page with a list for 5.7.2:

- http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Debug_tokens